# Mechanical oscillator and unbounded swings question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Will the mechanical oscillator with equation

$$my′′+cy′+ky=f(t)$$

have unbounded swings using

$$f(t)=\exp(−pt)\cosωt\quad ?$$

($−p+iω$ is a root of $mr^2+cr+k=0$).

I think the answer is yes, but I'm not sure I did it correctly.  How do I go through this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure how you arrived at that for the homogeneous. If you use the quadratic equation the roots are $r_{1,2} = \dfrac{-c \pm \sqrt{c^2 - 4km}}{2m}$. Am I missing something? Now that you have the homogeneous solution, you can find the particular solution and then analyze the behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

No, the swings will remain bounded (unless $c=0$, which is the situation of  resonance without dissipative forces). The reason is that the particular solution will be of the form $te^{-pt}\cos \omega t$. If $c>0$, then $p>0$ and the exponential term $e^{-pt}$ decays faster than the linear function $t$ grows.

You can also reach the same conclusion from physical consideration. The force $e^{-pt}\cos \omega t$ decreases to $0$ with time, while the dissipative force $-cy'$ keeps draining the energy at the same relative rate. In the long run, the energy  and amplitude of oscillations tend to zero.